# loading custom modules per domain on a single core app

Tags: php, laravel

i am currently learning laravel  and was wondering if its possible to load different customizations under each domain while using a single installation of laravel. let me explain what i mean.

if customer A has a has signed up to use my app and requested a few customizations to be done such as certain data be populated under a view or some kind of module that does something, i only want those to only be visible to him so that if customer b signs up he wont see the featues given to customer a.

Usually what companies does is have a copy of the app uploaded for each customer under their own hosting and each customer can have his or her own customization but when it comes time to upgrade you would have to update each app one by one and hope that nothing breaks.

Is there a way to just use one core installation of an app and have the customizations be loaded uniquly for each customer? would this be called multitennancy? or that terms means something else completly.

Sorry if i sound vague in any way its just that its something that ive wondered since day 1 of being a web developer and have seen many companies do what i mentioned above and i see this as bad practice and can be done better. but please correct me if im wrong.

ps: i know it must be possible because ive seen how with wordpress which has the multusite feature turned on, you can have a complete different views or plugins turned on or off per domain under a single installation of wp.

Comment: Why.. would you want that kind of setup for a base laravel app?

Comment: its the framework i want to use but i dont think it matters what i choose to use. or does it?

Comment: But surly you wouldn't make changes that would break laravel? 0_o;;

Comment: yea, it was just something mentioned. I've seen many companies make an app and provide it as a subscription and have a single copy of it for each customer on their host and in order to provide updates you would have to update it for each user. its a real waste of time. it would be better to have a single app and some how load the customizations for each user based on domain or whatever.

Comment: No, laravel is not like Wordpress in that respect. Even making multiple sites on a single wordpress instance is an unwise thing to do. 

You could build an app with laravel to do what you want however. But not as laravel is by itself. And I think your idea of "upgrading one by one and hoping nothing breaks" is disastrous, no one should be stupid enough to try such a thing. 

Maybe some companies do, but they shouldn't. Not with laravel.

Comment: I get what you mean about wasting time, but if the companies clients are important to them they should take the time to upgrade right. But in saying that for a framewrk like laravel each app should be handled individually and should never be "mass upgraded" in any way. You are asking for big trouble.

Comment: what if you have your core laravel app and each customer has their own custom module thats loaded specifically them and when you launch an update you update the core app rather than the modules. for example, if you look at shopify there are many customers using the core app but each person has their own theme and own installed or activated plugins. wouldnt this fall into the same category?

Comment: so if i signed up for shopify, they dont install a whole new copy of the app into a seperate host for me, i use the main app then i can go ahead and select what theme i want or customize the theme to my liking as well as choose what plugin i would like to use in the app be it admin or public page

Comment: yes, but you have to build that infrastructure first, laravel does not do that out of the box. You must build quite a lot of middleware to get that working first. Its just a framework, not a CMS or service like Wordpress or Shopify. Its not built to be used that way as it is.

Comment: take a look at October cms. its a cms written over Laravel and i think it supports multi tenancy.

Comment: i've played with it before but i'll look through it thanks